# Resource.designer.cs(32713, 4): [CS0433] The type 'Resource' exists in both. ( Maui, build error)

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have separated my Maui project to few libraries.
x.Services, x.Data and x.Core.
After that, I got an error -   `Resource.designer.cs(32713, 4): [CS0433] The type 'Resource' exists in both 'x.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'x.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`

This error I am getting when I am building a project.

I have deleted obj and bin folders from project and rebuild, but nothing changed.
All namespaces are unique, project versions are same.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in root namespace! There was not that library namespace, but another. I don't know why, I didn't change it.

[Image with location where you can solve that problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygmcx.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).